# Kibana dashboard not rendred

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, syslog, rsyslog

I'm running a dockerized elastic cluster composed of 3 master and 3 data nodes on AWS instances, using rsyslog and logstash, i collect and store syslog events on elasticsearch index.
till now everything was good until trying to build a vizualization dashboard on kibana.
working on kibana i notice that the request take too much time (even on a small number of syslog message 'less than 5000 records').
The following error 'Loading chunk 20 failed.' is repeated a lot.

[image]

The dashboard shows data once, and throws errors many times.

[image]

and

[image]

syslog event are stored as the following schema :

[image]

No error logs on both side, kibana and elastic server.
I tried many suggestion found on the internet :

- index re-create.
- re-deploy kibana on new EC2 instance.
- versions upgrade.
- machine ressource scaling.
- re-configure kibana.

Note : Currently i'm deploying the following version :

- ES : 8.10.0
- Logstash : 8.10.0
- Kibana : 8.10.0-1

P.S : same issue was also with version **8.9.0**.

i'm ready to provide any other further info could help to resolve this issue.

I appreciate any help from you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add kibana logs? and probably we need elasticsearch logs to investigate

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Stack Management - Kibana Data Views and deleting the Data View which you see as Index in Kibana-Discover?

If you do not have Lenses, Histograms etc. tied to your index, you can try deleting and recreating it again on Data Views.

Comment: Yes i deleted many time the dataview and also index but always same problem, the weired thing that i cannot understand is, the discover is working (only table) the vertical bar chart no.  sometimes the dashboard works but a refresh of filter change shows the same issue.

Comment: Did you check the Kibana Logs? it should be under root file of Kibana. If you do not have logs, I recommend adding the logging to your kibana.yml. Then restart Kibana and check the logs. Here is the source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/logging-settings.html

Comment: yes i checked logs, nothing weird appear, no errors only INFOs, i'm using docker deployment so i check logs using docker logs command.

Answer (score 0):

**good news :** Issue fixed, and cannot believe that the cause of all this pain was ***Nginx*** :/ even (basic nginx config), **Secret was at:** setting header "connection" to "upgrade" everything works nice.

```
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
```

unset header, issue return.
Hope that help others suffering same issue.